# Matching floating point number in scientific form with grep using regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, grep

I am stuck with matching scientific notation of floating point numbers with grep using the regular expression. My problem is as follows:

I want to get all the floating point numbers (expressed in scientific notation) in a file, but there are other strings in this file as well. 
The file content likes like this:

```
This product is subject to U.S. laws governing export and re-export.
Case run remote-shell.
33080  2.7122e-03  3.7837e-05  4.3489e-05  1.3267e-04  2.7229e-05  4.1196e-05  3.0528e-04  4.7660e-04  5.9506e-06  8.1338e-04  6.6428e-04  1.0230e-04  6.1385e-04  5.3061e-05  4.8918e-04  8.1832e-05  7.5350e-04  6.8355e-04  3.5495e-04  4.3668e-04  1.0076e-04  1.4759e-05  3.3033e-05  3.7662e-05  4.2165e-04  5.1842e-05  3.2158e-04  1.5356e-03  4.2839e-05  2.9283e-04  1.6930e-05  4.9191e-05  3.2135e-05  1.8665e-04  1.6677e-05  3.2952e-04  4.4912e-05  5.6932e-05  1.1145e-03  5.7499e-04  2.1972e-04  3.6925e-05  1.1579e-03  3.9610e-04  3.6176e-04  1.4320e-04  5.9517e-04  2.4946e-04  9.8161e-06  5.3642e-04  5.0760e-03  4.1630e-05  9.5973e-05  5.7817e-05  3.1283e-04  4.4210e-04  9.7502e-06  1.8566e+03  3.0613e-01  0:37:35 1922
33040  3.7547e-03  2.5260e-05  3.0029e-05  9.4277e-05  2.0479e-05  2.4130e-05  1.9597e-04  8.9547e-04  4.2917e-06  5.7030e-04  3.9776e-04  5.8403e-05  3.9431e-04  4.6212e-05  3.2378e-04  4.0916e-05  2.9765e-04  2.7011e-04  2.1954e-04  2.3628e-04  9.6072e-05  1.1480e-05  2.3660e-05  2.4469e-05  2.9498e-04  2.8080e-05  1.9791e-04  1.4410e-03  2.8925e-05  1.8617e-04  1.4366e-05  3.5216e-05  2.9843e-05  1.7923e-04  1.2372e-05  2.0673e-04  3.1176e-05  5.0167e-05  7.0653e-04  3.6454e-04  1.9928e-04  2.2903e-05  8.3425e-04  2.1208e-04  1.7543e-04  9.5440e-05  3.4135e-04  1.7607e-04  7.2080e-06  5.5701e-04  2.9932e-03  3.6117e-05  8.8722e-05  5.1176e-05  2.3192e-04  1.2000e-03  5.9996e-06  1.8570e+03  3.0613e-01  0:38:28 1962
```

I tried:

```
grep "[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]*[eE][+-][0-9]*" filename
```

It can indeed filter out all the numbers in scientific notation. But words like *re-export* and *remote-shell* are also filtered out. Which is weird to me. Then I removed the \? qualifier:

```
grep "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[eE][+-][0-9]*" filename
```

This time the words like *re-export* and *remote-shell* are not included. But I am really confused as the \? qualifier just represents the preceding item . (dot) is optional, why it makes all everything before it optional? Can anybody explain why this happens and provide a solution to just make the single item before the \? qualifier as optional as later on I also need to filter out numbers like this 2e-3

.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input as it's not clear if you want each fp number on it's own output line, or each line containing at least one fp number or something else. wrt `later on I also need to filter out numbers like this 2e-3` - just include whatever input you need to process in your question as you almost certainly don't need to do multiple passes of the input data bt we need to see truly representative input to be able to best help you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer as to *why* it happens is easy: the only obligatory subpatterns in your regex are `[eE][+-]`, so it will match any of `e-`, `e+`, `E-`, `E+`.

You need to make the *number* part compulsory. It depends on what kind of number format you need to support, but in most cases you may use `+` quantifier to match 1 or more occurrences:

```
"[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]\+[eE][+-][0-9]*"
                ^^
```

Comment: Perhaps the first `[0-9]` before the `.` should be mandatory too

Comment: @slezica: There are so many variations of this regex, I just want to point OP to the right direction.Maybe [`grep -E '([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|\.?[0-9]+)([eE][+-][0-9]+)?'`](https://regex101.com/r/8cz4np/1) would be even better. Just the `[0-9]` must match at least 1 occurrence of a digit.

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing that out for future readers, this is a perfectly good answer :) the upvote is mine